# SWIFT 3 Parse + FB Login

Tags: swift, facebook, parse-platform, swift3, facebook-sdk-4.0

I would like to make a custom login button with 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'framework.

regarding the documentation of Parse, it should be:

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
 (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
 if let user = user {
 if user.isNew {
 print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
 } else {
 print("User logged in through Facebook!")
 }
 } else {
 print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
 }
}
```

The error is:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'permissions'
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Have you setup the SDK ?

Comment: Actually, the app worked well under swift 2. After the Swift 3 migration and the update of pods for Parse and Facebook frameworks, I saw that 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'framework works differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add the permissions

```
let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions) { (user : PFUser?, error: Error?) in
```

Comment: Thanks! I will lso inform the Parse team to update their documentations. By the way, Streetholder seems to be a interesting project. Is it yours?

Comment: Yes it is, running on parse ;)